# Unable to run mpi4py program on multiple machines

Tags: python, python-3.x, mpi, nfs, mpi4py

I have a very simple mpi python program

```
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.rank
name = MPI.Get_processor_name()

print('name: ', name, ' rank: ', rank)

MPI.Finalize
```

I have installed nfs-kernel-server on the main machine and nfs-common on the client machine. I followed the instructions from this page [here](https://www.tecmint.com/install-nfs-server-on-ubuntu/)

now I use the following command to execute my python mpi program:

```
mpirun --hostfile myhostfile.txt -np 8 python hello.py
```

When I do so I get the following error:

```
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] *** Process received signal ***
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] Signal code:  (128)
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] Failing at address: (nil)
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 0] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12890)[0x7f5a89bf0890]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 1] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x3d)[0x7f5a8988498d]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 2] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.20(opal_argv_free+0x29)[0x7f5a89e4b519]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 3] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.20(+0x283cb)[0x7f5a8a0d73cb]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 4] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.20(orte_util_add_hostfile_nodes+0xc1)[0x7f5a8a0d83f1]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 5] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-rte.so.20(orte_ras_base_allocate+0xd3d)[0x7f5a8a1097fd]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 6] /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopen-pal.so.20(opal_libevent2022_event_base_loop+0xdc9)[0x7f5a89e63209]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 7] mpirun(+0x74a3)[0x55a0de7394a3]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 8] mpirun(+0x5aea)[0x55a0de737aea]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [ 9] /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x7f5a8980eb97]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] [10] mpirun(+0x59ea)[0x55a0de7379ea]
[mahmoud-desktop:05540] *** End of error message ***
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Question: How can I fix this error

Comment: what is the content of your `myhostfile.txt`? which version of Open MPI are you running?

Comment: the myhostfile has the following: mahmoud@mahmoud-desktop, mahmoud@mahmoud-390, each in a separate line. I have downloaded the openmpi files requires, but as I checked the version of I found that I am using MPICH version 3.3.2

Comment: Here is something interesting I tried. I have a raspberry pi board and I downloaded openmpi on it and I downloaded openmpi on another desktop PC and I tried running the program from the raspberry pi and it gave me an error also. I tried do the same thing between 2 raspberry pi's and they worked fine.

Comment: the stack trace you posted is from Open MPI. if you use `mpirun` or `mpiexec` from MPICH, the behavior is undefined. I guess your PC is x86, and rpi is ARM, so at the very least, you need to build Open MPI with --enable-heterogeneous (this is lightly tested, feel free to report any issue at https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi/issues)

Comment: I think I found the problem. I removed all the packages on my desktop and I installed the following packages libopenmpi-dev openmpi-bin libhdf5-openmpi-dev both on the Rpi and Desktop PC. I ran mpirun --version on both platforms. On the Pi i got version 3.1.3 and on the PC I get 2.1.1, this will create a problem correct? I will try building from the source and I will add --enable-hetrogeneous and I will if new problems occur

Comment: Sounds like a plan!